# Create JSON with multilevel

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop

How is the multilevel JSON set up in this case?

```
var quiz = {};

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {     
quiz['Questions'] = {
    Question: Question,
    Answers: Answers,
    Correct: Correct
    };
    };

json_quizModule = JSON.stringify({QuizModule: quiz }, null, "\t");
alert(json_quizModule)
```

Now all of it is under the parameter "Question". But I trying the achieve this structure of a JSON:

```
{
"QuizModule": {
    "Questions": {
        "Question": "Write your question here" 
                                 { "Answers": "sds" 
                                          { "Correct": false
                                          }
                                 }
    }

}
}
```

I'm quite new to JSON, and can there also be several parameters names "Question", in case there are multiple questions?

Really thankful for some help here!

**UPDATE:**

Jquery:

```
    var quiz = {};

    var quiz = {
    Questions: []
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var q = questions[i];
    var answers = q.getAnswers()
    quiz.Questions.push({
    Question: q.getQuestion()
    });

    for(var n = 0; n < answers.length; n++){

    var quiz = {
    Answers: []
    };

    quiz.Questions.Answers.push({       
        Answers: answers[n].getAnswer(),
        Correct: answers[n].getCorrect()
     });

     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quiz['Questions'] = { ... }` will replace `Questions` with a new object each iteration of the loop.  You should make that an array, then push objects into it.

```
var quiz = {
    Questions: []
};

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    quiz.Questions.push({
        Question: Question,
        Answers: Answers,
        Correct: Correct
    });
}
```

EDIT: `var quiz = {Answers: []};`.  That re-creates the *entire* `quiz` variable! You don't want to do that.  You want to make a new array, fill it up, then add it to the current question.

```
var quiz = {
    Questions: []
};

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var q = questions[i];
    var answers = q.getAnswers();
    var AnswersArray = []; // Add this array

    for(var n = 0; n < answers.length; n++){
        // Fill the new array
        AnswersArray.push({       
            Answers: answers[n].getAnswer(),
            Correct: answers[n].getCorrect()
        });
    } 

    // Push everything into the main array
    quiz.Questions.push({
        Question: q.getQuestion(),
        Answers: AnswersArray
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked well! But how am I pushing the "Answers" into the "Questions" parameter? I made an update of my question above, with a code that is not working, if you had time to give me another hint on that? :)

Comment: @Kim: There ya go.  Try that! :-)

Comment: Ah! Brilliant! You just saved me alot of time! And thank you for your time! Really appriciate :)

Answer (score 3):

To have more than one Question section you need the following structure

```
"QuizModule": {
    "Questions": [
        "Question": "Write your question here" {
        "Answers": "sds" {
            "Correct": false
        }

    },
        "Question": "Write your question here" {
        "Answers": "sds" {
            "Correct": false
        }]

    }
}
```

notice [ instead of { . [ is used to indicate array

It can be achieved using the push method like

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    quiz['Questions'].push({
        Question: Question,
        Answers: Answers,
        Correct: Correct
    });
};
```